# Is there a way to send a remote lock/unlock message to an iOS device with Cydia?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, screen-lock

I want to be able to trigger my iphone to unlock from a webserver. Is there a way to send a command over LAN to it to unlock using Cydia?

Answer (score -1):

The only way I can think of doing this is by downloading Veency and a program that supports it, eg. VNC viewer